# Create Array JSON in Indicator

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, express

I'm using ExpressJS to create JSON in my application **Road Trip Today** and i'll create new array JSON in indicator **0** - **0** to list parking.

How to Create new Array in indicator **0** to **0**?

Example JSON:

```
{ "data": [
    { "speed": "0" },
    { "speed": "10" },
    { "speed": "2" },
    { "speed": "5" },
    { "speed": "4" },
    { "speed": "9" },
    { "speed": "0" },
    { "speed": "2" },
    { "speed": "4" },
    { "speed": "33" },
    { "speed": "0" },
]};
```

to:

```
{ "data": [{
    "1": [
        { "speed": "10" },
        { "speed": "2" },
        { "speed": "5" },
        { "speed": "4" },
        { "speed": "9" },
    ],
    "2": [
        { "speed": "2" },
        { "speed": "4" },
        { "speed": "33" },
    ]
}]};
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some code of what you have already tried.

Comment: Ah, it seems the OP wants to split the array wherever there’s a 0.

Comment: Any reason why your result `data` is an array?

Comment: Do you really need that target structure? IMHO it’s overly complex without any obvious reason, there’s at least one extra level.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pjgr30pu/

Comment: Check the answer. It can be helpful to you and self explanatory too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. Simple logic:

```js
var arrayData = { "data": [
    { "speed": "0" },
    { "speed": "10" },
    { "speed": "2" },
    { "speed": "5" },
    { "speed": "4" },
    { "speed": "9" },
    { "speed": "0" },
    { "speed": "2" },
    { "speed": "4" },
    { "speed": "33" },
    { "speed": "0" },
]}; 
var key = 0;
var innerArray=[{}];
arrayData.data.forEach((obj, index)=>{
   if(obj.speed === "0"){
     //check that this is not last object 
     if(index+1 !== arrayData.data.length){
      key++;
      innerArray[0][key]=[];
     }
   } else {
      innerArray[0][key].push(obj); 
   }
});
var resultArray  = { "data": innerArray}; 
console.log(resultArray)
```

Comment: Extra `"3": []`

Comment: Edited my answer @dfsq

Comment: Glad to help you @DSSTR

Answer (score 0):

```
 const result = [];
 input.reduce((trip, {speed}) => speed === "0" && trip.length ? (result.push(trip), []) : (trip.push({speed}), trip), []);
```

Just start a new trip whenever a 0 occurs, if not just add the data to the trip.

---

If you prefer imperative instead of functional programming:

```
const result = [];
var trip = [];
for(const {speed} of input){
   if(speed === "0" && trip.length){
     result.push(trip);
     trip = [];
   }else{
     trip.push({speed});
   }
}
```